# Picking a random paragraph jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to randomly display a single paragraph from a selection of paragraphs when I click a button on my page. Right now it will display a paragraph if I hard code in a number, but when I try to randomly choose a paragraph (using `$( "p:nth-child(set)" )`it is breaking.

My Javascript is as follows:

```
$( "#toggleweight" ).click(function() {
  var set =Math.floor((Math.random()* $('p').length )+1);
  $.ajax({success:function(result){
       $( "p:nth-child(set)" ).fadeIn( 3200 );
    }});
});
```

My HTML:

```
        <div id="button">
          <a class="btn" href="#" id="toggleweight">Cool button. </a>
        </div>
        <div id = "button2">
          <% array = ["ASDF", "FDSA"] %>
          <% array.each do |display| %>
          <p class="btn" style="display: none"><%= display %></p>
         <% end %>
        </div>
```

Comment: You're not treating `set` as a variable in the selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that set is a string. you need `"p:nth-child(" + set+ ")"`

EDIT: In order to get rid of the currently paragraph and show a new one, you will want to add a class when you select it, then fade that class out...

```
$.ajax({
   success:function(result) {
      $(".shown").removeClass("shown").fadeOut(3200);
      $( "p:nth-child("+set+")" ).fadeIn( 3200 ).addClass("shown");
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks! Also, I realize this is outside of the scope of the question, but do you know how I would code it such that when I click the button a second time it will get rid of the previously displayed `<p>` and display a new randomly selected `<p>`?

Answer (score 0):

set is a variable so try this

```
$( "p:nth-child("+set+")" ).fadeIn( 3200 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$( "p:nth-child(set)" ).fadeIn( 3200 );
```

Should be:

```
$( "p:nth-child("+set+")" ).fadeIn( 3200 );
```